# Converter valores de uma coluna em tipo date MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá, estou com dificuldades de alterar os valores de uma coluna para o tipo date no seguinte código:

```
SELECT
    t2.shopee_transaction_identifier,
    CAST (t2.payment_value AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS payment_value,
    CAST (t2.real_payment_date AS date)

FROM 
    brbi_opspay.pmtdata_shopee_movfile_santander_br_daily AS t2

WHERE shopee_transaction_identifier  LIKE 'PT%'
```

acontece que na coluna original os dados são do tipo varchar e da seguinte forma 'ddmmaaaa', quando executo o código acima aparece o seguinte erro:

Invalid format: "09022023" is too short
Value cannot be cast to date: 09022023

Alguém sabe o que pode estar ocorrendo?

Obrigada :)

Comment: Já tentou usar `STR_TO_DATE(t2.real_payment_date ,'%d%m%Y')`?

Comment: Sim, não roulou :/

Comment: acho que entendi teoricamente, tente usar um alias, em   `STR_TO_DATE(t2.real_payment_date, '%d%m%Y') AS real_payment_date` se ainda dara erro

Answer (score 0):

Consegui da seguinte forma:

```
 CAST((SUBSTRING(real_payment_date,5,4) || '-' ||SUBSTRING(real_payment_date,3,2)||'-'||SUBSTRING(real_payment_date,1,2)) AS DATE) AS real_payment_date
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).